# Native code in Android with JNA

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

Is it possible to use JNA in Android? I need to reuse some existing shared libs written in C++, or compile new ones with the NDK toolset.

The information in JNA's repositiory seems a bit outdated, from the times of Eclipse:

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/AndroidDevelopmentEnvironment.md

Don't want to downmigrate my project to Eclipse, and Android Studio still has
"experimental" support for NDK.

Comment: @DanielNugent The jna-android repo you've linked hasn't been updated since 2012. I don't think it should be recommended. Probably just go with the main JNA repo?